# How to search for users by both first and last name with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a basic collection of users that have their `firstName`, `lastName` and a few other details.

How would I simply search for users by a combination of both names, or partial search?

For example, for a collection of:

```
{
   firstName: Bob,
   lastName: Jerry
}, {
   firstName: Clark,
   lastName: Mcbobby
}
```

If the search term was `bob`, both users would be returned since the first documents `firstName` is bob, and the last users `lastName` contains `bob`. If `bob j` was the search term, just the first document would be returned since if both names are combine, it equals `Bob Jerry` which matches the search term.

I tried creating a basic `aggregate` to concatenate the names and then make a match, although Mongoose kept throwing me an error of: `Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`.

Here is my current code:

```
User.aggregate({
    $project: { "name" : { $concat : [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] } },
    $match: {"name": {$regex: "/bob j/i"}}
}).exec(function(err, results) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see couple of mistakes in your code causing undesired result.

1. Aggregation pipeline accepts array of aggregation framework operations. In your case, you are missing `[]` operator. It should be like

   `User.aggregate([{$project...},{$match...}])`
2. In $match stage you are using regex, if you  are using `/../` style of regex, you don't need to wrap it around string quotes. It should be `/bob j/i`

Here is finished example:

```
User.aggregate([
  {$project: { "name" : { $concat : [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] } }},
  {$match: {"name": {$regex: /bob j/i}}}
]).exec(function(err, result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

You should see `[ { _id: 574c3e20be214bd4078a9149, name: 'Bob Jerry' } ]` on screen.

Comment: Ahhh okay, so the error was being thrown since my aggregate pipeline was not an array. Your fixes work perfectly, thanks Saleem.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest mongodb version **4.2** you can use [**`$regexMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) aggregation. Something like this

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$regexMatch": {
      "input": { "$concat": ["$firstName", " ", "$lastName"] },
      "regex": "a",  //Your text search here
      "options": "i"
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments for the aggregate function must be an array containing pipeline stage documents

```
var query = 'bob j';
Users.aggregate([ //pipeline array
 {$project:{name: { $concat : [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] }}}, //stage1
 {$match : { name: { $regex: query, $options:'i'}}} //stage2
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the aggregation framework to select documents where the a give value is in "firstName" or "lastName".

```
var reg = new RegExp(/bob/, 'i');
User.find({
    '$or': [
        { 'firstName': reg }, 
        { 'lastName': reg }
    ]
}).exec(function(err, results) { // Do something }
```

If you want based on the concatenated value, then:

```
User.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "name": { "$concat" : [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] } } },  
    { "$match" : { "name": /bob j/i } }  
]).exec(function(err, results) { // Do something }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested and it works fine:

imagine the collection is like this `{name :{first:'','last:''}}`

the query should be like this: `db.collectionName.find({ $or : [
      { 'name.first':{ $regex: 'search', $options: '-i' } },
      { 'name.last': { $regex: 'search', $options: '-i' } },
    ]})`;

Answer (score -3):

You could use $or ([see the doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/or/))

```
User.find({ $or: [
  {$match: {"firstName": {$regex: "/bob j/i"}}},
  {$match: {"lastName": {$regex: "/bob j/i"}}}
] });
```

Not tested

Comment: Won't that match 'firstName' OR 'lastName'? Therefore having "bob j" not matching either since it's a combination of both?