# Case insensitive search in concat firstName and lastName in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to search fullName by using firstName and lastName fields for that i am using below filter

```
collections.find({$expr:{$eq:["test test", {$concat:["$firstName", ' ', "$lastName"]}]}})
```

But this need to be case insensitive filter. Let me know if is there any way to do.

Comment: got the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525675/how-to-search-for-users-by-both-first-and-last-name-with-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Create a case-insensitive index:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive